# WP7 Transition on Visibility change on a Listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, controls, transition

I have a listbox where I change the Visibility depending upon events that happen on the page.
I am doingthis via Binding and its all working fine i.e. the Listbox disappears as it should and is shown correctly when I want it to be.

I am wondering how easy it is to implements some sort of transition when the Listbox is shown/hidden?

I ma currently using page transitions fine, but am not really sure how practical it is to try and implement something at an individual control level.

Is there a (relatively) straightforward approach to this?

- thanks

Comment: What kind of animation/transition you are thinking of? Explain a bit clear

Answer (score 0):

To start learning about animating controls, start by looking at http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/29/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-29-animations/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134792(v=expression.40).aspx